# UnicodeDecodeError: Unexpected end of data issue

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode, praw

I am currently extracting comments from various subreddits on Reddit using praw and trying to calculate their sentiment and add them to a database.
It works by reading from a file that contains subreddit names in order to know which subreddit to pull the comments from.

```
with open('subs.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        string = line.strip()


        for submission in reddit.subreddit(string).hot(limit=10):
            subreddit = reddit.subreddit(line.strip())
            name = str(subreddit.display_name)
            comments = submission.comments.list()
            for c in comments:
                if isinstance(c, MoreComments):
                    continue
                #print c.body
                author = c.author
                score = c.score
                created_at = c.created_utc
                upvotes = c.ups
                #print c.score
                comment_sentiment = getSentiment(c.body)
                subreddit_sentiment += comment_sentiment
                num_comments += 1
```

What I have currently implemented works fine up until it reaches a certain comment where it throws the following error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 8-10: unexpected end of data
```

I have looked at a bunch of different questions on here where people have encountered the same issue, but the solutions given did not seem to help my problem.

The full stack trace is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "extract.py", line 48, in <module>
    comment_sentiment = getSentiment(c.body)
  File "/Users/b38/Desktop/FlaskApp/sentiment_analysis.py", line 93, in getSentiment
    tagged_sentences = makeTag(pos_tag_text, max_key_size, dictionary)
  File "/Users/b38/Desktop/FlaskApp/sentiment_analysis.py", line 106, in makeTag
    return [addTag(sentence, max_key_size, dictionary) for sentence in postagged_sentences]
  File "/Users/b38/Desktop/FlaskApp/sentiment_analysis.py", line 119, in addTag
    expression_word = ' '.join([word[0] for word in sentence[i:j]]).lower().encode('utf-8',errors='ignore')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 8-10: unexpected end of data
```

I've been racking my brain trying to think of various ways to solve this issue and unfortunately I'm lost. Is it something to do with reading from the file containing the subreddits or would it be concerning the limit of pulling data with praw? I have tried to isolate the problem but can't seem to shake this error.

Would anyone be able to help me fix this issue? I would appreciate any insight.
Many thanks.

**EDIT:** 
sentiment_analysis.py

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    import sys
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
    import pandas as pd
    import nltk
    import yaml
    import sys
    import os
    import re

//splitting the text initially 
def splitString(text):
    nltk_splitter = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
    nltk_tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.TreebankWordTokenizer()
    sentences = nltk_splitter.tokenize(text)
    tokenized_sentences = [nltk_tokenizer.tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
    return tokenized_sentences

def tagWords(sentence,max_key_size, dictionary, tag_stem=False):
    # Tag all possible sentences
    tagged_sentence = []
    length = len(sentence)
    if max_key_size == 0:
        max_key_size = length
    i = 0
    while (i < length):
        j = min(i + max_key_size, length)
        tagged = False
        while (j > i):
            expression_word = ' '.join([word[0] for word in sentence[i:j]]).lower().encode('utf-8',errors='ignore')         // here is where it gets caught 
            expression_stem = ' '.join([word[1] for word in sentence[i:j]]).lower().encode('utf-8',errors='ignore')

            if tag_stem == True:
                word = expression_word
            else:
                word = expression_word
             ....
```

Comment: The traceback says the failing line is encoding, but the error is a UnicodeDecodeError.  Since the error is in sentiment_analysis.py, showing that code would be more useful.  I'm going to guess there is a `reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` somewhere as well, since the normal default decode is `ascii`.

Comment: @ekhumoro By the error message `sentence` is probably a byte string and being sliced.  Slice UTF-8 in the wrong place and you'd get `unexpected end of data`.

Comment: It looks like the library expects Unicode.  Try opening the file with `io.open('subs.txt',encoding='utf8')`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for your response, I added in your suggestion `io.open('subs.txt', encoding='utf-8')`, which worked well - it managed to decode the initial string it was having trouble with. However, 800 comments later it found another string it couldn't decode haha. I will edit my original question with the useful parts of sentiment_analysis.py. It does include `reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')`, could that be what is causing the issue?

Comment: Best practice is to decode to Unicode when loading data, process everything as Unicode, and encode back to UTF8 when storing back to file/database. The reload trick is bad practice because it hides mixing of byte and Unicode strings, and many libraries rely on the expected ascii default.  If possible switch to Python 3, which eliminates the implicit conversion between bytes and Unicode.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I see, thank you for all your help and advice. My issue seems to be resolved for now. :)

Comment: Try python3 @RachelSolomon

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the string explicitly:

```
c.body.encode('utf-8')
```